# Launch Chrome as application

Tags: windows, chromium

I am writing a web app. I would like the users to be able to launch a Chromium browser (SRWare Iron) without an address bar or tabs, just a frame.

Is it possible? How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 4):

The functionality I'm looking for was the `--app="http://mywebapp.internal"` switch

Comment: You don't have to apologize, answering your own questions is encouraged.  They even have a badge for it - "Self-Learner."

Answer (score 1):

[Full screen is currently only available by pressing F11](http://www.browser-watch.com/2008/09/19/full-screen-google-chrome-on-open/)

> - Real full screen mode is available in the latest release of Google
>     Chrome. You simply need to press F11.
> - For clarification – there is no full-screen mode in Google Chrome yet.
>     This simply opens the browser
>     maximized.
>
> One thing that many users may find
>   frustrating is that Google Chrome
>   opens in window mode. Thankfully there
>   is a simple fix for this. By editing
>   the Google Chrome shortcut, you simply
>   need to add the -start-maximized
>   parameter to the end of the shortcut
>   line. Your new shortcut line should
>   look something like this:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -start-maximized
> ```
>
> Problem solved! Chrome will now open
>   in full-screen mode.

Comment: Note I'm still looking for some way to force it to run that way

Answer (score 1):

[Google Support - Application shortcuts](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95710) reports:

> You can create application shortcuts to websites that you regularly visit, as well as apps that you've installed from the Chrome Web Store. These shortcuts can be placed on your computer desktop and menus for quick and easy access.